# Int Object Not Callable (Permutations and Combinations)

Tags: python

I have recently made a multi-purpose calculator with 45+ different functions. The newest addition to the calculator has been permutations and combinations. Permutations works fine, but when I try to use combinations, I get this error:

> 'int' object is not callable

I ask the user for the values of `n` and `r`, and then the program spits out all possible combinations for those two numbers.

```
def comb(num1, num2):
    return (factorial(num1))/(factorial(num2)(factorial(num1 - num2)))

print("You chose combinations")
num1 = int(input("Enter the value of n: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the value of r: "))
print("There are", str(comb(num1, num2)), "possible combinations.")
```

The solution seems super simple, but I just don't know what it is. Either I am blind and the solution is staring me in the face or I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Python doesn't do implicit multiplication -- you need an explicit `*` in your denominator.

Comment: You can't do `factorial(num2)(factorial(num1 - num2))`, because `factorial(num2)` is an integer. You probably want to do something like this: `factorial(num2)*(factorial(num1 - num2))`.

Comment: Aside: you should probably use `//` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the correct multiplication operator:

```
(factorial(num1))/(factorial(num2) * (factorial(num1 - num2)))
```

What you tried to do in the denominator was

```
(func(n)(expr))
```

**func(n)** is an integer, and you followed that with something in parentheses.  The parser thought you were trying to use the value returned from **factorial** as a function name and give it an argument (which was the return value from **factorial(num1 - num2) ).

Comment: Yep. I'm blind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You accidently called factorial or something**

I just cleaned your snippet for you

```
def comb(num1, num2):
    numer = factorial(num1);
    denom = factorial(num2) * factorial(num1 - num2);
    return numer/denom;
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because Python doesn't do implicit multiplication (i.e. you can't do something like this:

```
4(factorial(5))
```

And expect to get an answer, because Python doesn't work that way).

You need to insert the multiplication signs manually:

```
factorial(num1) / (factorial(num2) * factorial(num1 - num2))
```

*Note that in my answer, I got rid of some brackets for you, as you don't need them.*

Comment: Er, the OP *does* need the parentheses, or at least two more than you've used.  The formula requires _dividing_ by (num1-num2)!, not multiplying by it.

Comment: @DSM Yeah, I got a little excited. Thanks for the catch!